# What year is this Mongoose?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

I bought this bike about 15 years ago and want to get it back to its original state. What year is it? How did it originally look? I've attached some shots, there don't seem to be any serial numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observe a V brake on the rear wheel, which is relatively modern.  I'd guess mid 2000's making it not very old when you originally got the bike.

Curiously there is no trace of a front brake.  The USA doesn't require two independent brakes, so likely this was sold in the US, or perhaps someone removed the brake for some reason.   If you intend a concourse restoration, that might be hard to achieve.

It is definitely a mongoose - the logo on the chainring and on the right-hand dropout matches:

[image]

Aside, your saddle is mounted backward and the seatpost is rotated 180 degrees in the frame.  As pictured that would be horrible to ride.

Do please air up the tyres - that protects the rim from the ground.

Comment: Thanks Criggie!

Answer (score 6):

It looks a lot like this 1999 Supergoose.

[image]

Based [pictures posted at BMXmuseum.com](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?year-start=1990&year-end=2024&company%5B%5D=55&model=149) it looks like your frame was made in 1998 and 1999. They changed the rear drop outs in 2000

From Wikipedia

> Skip Hess started BMX Products, Inc. out of his home in Simi Valley,
> California in September 1974 with his first product being the famous
> Motomag One wheel.
> Mongoose was sold to American Group in 1985 and marketed by their
> Service Cycle subsidiary.
>
> Bell Sports bought American Group in 1995 and sold Mongoose to
> Brunswick Outdoor Recreation Group in 1997.
>
> Brunswick sold Mongoose to Pacific Cycle in 2000 and Pacific Cycle was
> bought by Montreal-based Dorel Industries in 2004.
>
> As of 2018, Mongoose models are available through Pacific Cycle in Madison, Wisconsin.
>
> On 11 October 2021 Pon Holdings, headquartered in Amsterdam, the Netherlands announced that they acquired US-based bike
> company Dorel Sports. By combining Pon.Bike and Dorel Sports, a
> leading bicycle company in the world will be created, with a combined
> revenue of around 2.5 billion euro.